# Cast an object to its specific type at runtime Java

Tags: java, dispatch

Suppose I have the following class hierarchy:

```
abstract class Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
```

Consider the following code:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Animal animal = cat;
        
        talk(dog);
        talk(cat);
        talk(animal);
        
        List<Animal> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(cat);
        list.add(dog);
        for(Animal animal : list)
            talk(animal);
    }

    public static void talk(Animal animal) {
        System.out.println("Animal");
    }
    
    public static void talk(Dog dog) {
        System.out.println("Dog");
    }
    
    public static void talk(Cat cat) {
        System.out.println("Cat");
    }
}
```

When I run the program I get as output

```
Dog
Cat
Animal
Animal
Animal
```

This means that when referenced with an Animal reference, each Dog and Cat is seen just as an Animal of no specific kind.  If I know the specific kind of the animal at compile time I can cast that animal to its specific kind and the desired talk method is dispatched;  but if I am given a list of animal and I don't know at compile time the exact kind of each of them, how can I make the program invoke the specific talk method?

Comment: Overload resolution is going via the variable type, not the actual type behind it. You need to do `instanceof` and then cast. You can not do this dynamically since the route has to be carved in stone at compile-time. It would probably be better to just have one method and have an `instanceof` switch in it.

Comment: If such a dynamic cast would be allowed, you could easily create a program that compiles although it shouldnt compile. For example suppose you only created a method overload for `Dog` and `Cat`, when you get an arbitrary `Animal`. Now, after you compiled this code, you add a `Fish` to the inheritance tree. Which method should the fish go? There is no matching overload. Should it fail on runtime only? Such a feature is kinda going against Javas design goals.

Comment: create an method called `talk()` in `Animal` and override in subtypes, better still use composition and strategy pattern and provide a "talk" strategy.  Currently you lower bound for your list will always be `Animal`.